# Return distinct column1s data when every row for column2 is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to return a distinct listing of column 1's "table_ID" when column 2 is "only" null in "DATA_TABLE".

```
Table_ID | Value

1        | null

2        | 55

1        | null

3        | 5

3        | null
```

So, in this query - I would only wish to return Table_ID of 1, 2 has no nulls, and 3 contains something that is not null.
I believe this should be satisfactory though this statement may not be efficient as VALUE is not indexed.

```
select table_id from RN_QOS_DATA_0011 group by table_id having max(samplevalue) is null
```

To make it more difficult there is are an unknown amount of DATA_TABLES and I need to do the above check in each one; how would I loop through all of these?

In trying to define a cursor I am running into difficulty - I have a table with a listing of each DATA_TABLEs name and attempting to iterate over it to no avail.

Here's what I have for my cursor - and it's complaining that RN_TABLE is not declared

```
DECLARE @RN_TABLE varchar(50)
DECLARE RN_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY static For 
select r_table from S_DATA

OPEN RN_CURSOR 
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM RN_CURSOR INTO @RN_TABLE
WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
select table_id from @RN_TABLE group by table_id having max(Datavalue) is null
FETCH NEXT FROM RN_CURSOR INTO @RN_TABLE
END
END
close RN_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE RN_CURSOR
```

Comment: You should be storing all the data in a single table.  Multiple tables with the same schema is a sign of a problem in the database structure.

Comment: I don't have the ability to resolve that. I merely support the product, not develop it.

Comment: `@RN_TABLE` isn't a table. When you fetch into it, it's a varchar variable without a column name. so selecting `table_id from @RN_TABLE` is trying to select a column, which doesn't exist, from a variable that isn't a table variable.

Comment: Gotcha; thank you for clarifying scsimon

Answer (score 1):

`having max(samplevalue) is null` is overkill; a simple `where samplevalue is null` is easier.

You can join all the tables' results by using `UNION`, which also removes duplicates:

```
SELECT table_id FROM table1 WHERE samplevalue IS NULL
UNION
SELECT table_id FROM table2 WHERE samplevalue IS NULL
UNION
SELECT table_id FROM table3 WHERE samplevalue IS NULL
UNION
<...and so on...>
SELECT table_id FROM table999 WHERE samplevalue IS NULL).
```

Comment: There is an unknown amount of tables - anywhere between 1 to over 500. Is there not a way to iterate over this?

Comment: No, databases iterate over data, not over tables. As others said, having more than one table with the same structure smells like a seriously flawed design, and you are at the point where you pay the price for it. A _Bad Design_ is not bad because someone says so, but because it produces issues like yours.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `UNION ALL`? Seems to me that `UNION` is redundant with `GROUP BY table_id` as they both remove duplicates.

Comment: you are probably right, I was in a hurry and didn't think it through.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of `table_id`s, then this might be faster:

```
select t.table_id
from tables t
where not exists (select 1
                  from RN_QOS_DATA_0011 d
                  where d.table_id = t.table_id and d.samplevalue is not null
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `RN_QOS_DATA_0011(table_id, samplevalue)`.

If you want to get all `table_id`s that are not null in one of the tables, you can extend the `where` using `or` and the subquery.

I would recommend that you reconsider your data structure.  Having multiple different tables with the same data is bad idea.  If necessary, you can run code when the tables are created to load them into a master table, which can then be used much more conveniently -- without cursors.

Comment: Ahh; so I forgot to mention - the table_id's are unique to each RN_* (r_Table). In this example, it looks like if it's missing in any table it will return?